# Test for difference of variances in populations with different means

Tags: variance, bootstrap-sampling

I have two samples A and B, both of size 72, drawn from two different populations. I do not know anything about the population, only that they are non normal at all.

I want to know the probability that sample B is drawn from a population whose variance $Var_B$ is smaller than $Var_A$, the variance of the population of sample A, i.e. I need to estimate $P(Var_A>Var_B)$

Data are under the form of percentages, hence from 0 to 1.
The means $\mu$ of the two samples are 0.16 and and 0.10

I have performed nonparametric boostrapping, finding out that $P(Var_A>Var_B)=0.95$.
So far so good.
However, the samples have different means.
Do you think I should use some sort of normalized variance, like $Var' =\frac{Var}{\mu(1-\mu)}$?

If I use bootstrapping on this quantity, I find that t $P(Var'_B<Var'_A)= 0.72$.
It does not look conclusive.

Can you suggest another approach? 
Do you think I should worry about the samples not having the same means? 
Do you think that Levene's and Fligner-Killen  test can help in any way (I know they only test the hypothesis that variances are equal)?

Comment: Not sure if it makes sense, but what if you subtracted out the sample mean (which is close to the true mean with some confidence you can estimate), then did the tests? At least it could help bound the error.